# Connecting to a remote server and switching user with bash/expect

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

First post, thanks in advance for any help.

I'm somewhat new to scripting in general but I've managed to build a nice wrapper in bash that's designed to collect some variables and then make some connections to a couple of remote boxes and do some things related to a web statistics system and launch some hadoop processes. Basically a series of tedious tasks that I'm trying to automate. (unnecessary details complete).

The problem I'm running into is finding a way to effectively connect to those remove servers, authenticate as as a regular user, then switch users for various tasks. Here's the relevant code:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #Script's run as root. this asks for the sudoers pass
    read -p "Enter password for $SUDO_USER: " -s password
    #Defines some testing commands I want to pass to a remote box
    CMD="hostname; id; sudo su -; id; pwd;"
    #launches an expect script with some defined variables as arguments.
    /home/ME/scripts/derp.expect $SUDO_USER $definedremoteserver "$command" "$password"
```

Now the expect script being used:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    #expect script to help with SSH connections for the urchinizer bash script
    set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
    set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]
    set arg3 [lindex $argv 2]
    set arg4 [lindex $argv 3]
    spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $arg1@$arg2 "$arg3"
    expect "password:"
    send "$arg4\r"
    interact
    expect "password"
    send "$arg4\r"
    interact
```

I'm having trouble determining why this fails. I've researched quite a bit and have tried numerous variations of the code. Basically when I run this, it takes my pass and I'm able to make the initial connection. Then the script tries to switch user and the second expect fails. The first 'id' and 'hostname' output successfully. When the user switch happens, the second expect doesn't work and I'm left with just a password prompt. I enter my pass anyway (which displays in plain text for some reason) and the script just hangs without outputting the second 'id' and 'pwd' commands I'm trying to use to verify that this is working.

If I actually login to that box and do a sudo -i or sudo su - this is what the password prompt looks like:

```
    [sudo] password for my.name:
```

So for the second (not working) expect, I've tried a few different variations with somewhat different results but no success.

Sorry for the long post. This has been driving be nuts. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a smarter way to handle this? Anyone spot any obvious mistakes? Also, a secondary question... how do wildcards work in those expect lines?

Comment: As you've tagged this bash, I'm assuming Linux/Unix, not widows. Did you try replacing '\r' for '\n' in your expect script? This would be more standard for linux. And you're sure your **remote** sudoers file, user premissions, etc are setup correctly? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use some scripting language as Perl, Python or Ruby with some module for SSH.

For instance, using Perl and the [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) module:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
my $output = $ssh->capture({stdin_data => "$sudo_password\n"},
                           'sudo', '-Sk', '-p', '', '--',
                           'ls', '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Public Key Authentication" instead of "Password Authentication" in OpenSSH.

1: create the private/public key pair for the user you want to login with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Do not supply passwords, choose the default path (enter, enter, enter).
This should be done for each of your SSH machines (clients and servers).

2: from each client machine you want to login from, copy your new public key file content to your favourite text editor (notepad, gvim, etc)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You should now have all your client's public keys pasted into your editor, something like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAt9sGP1PKR1XzpozHQc9ufyzOnePHCnRzUhdfSvfQTzJO28CgnHwhANdaBeOrLq5b+VOoPJFj5NquYXmJ6YikSJCwHlvfewA/5p0IkucsJLxqYQMDRhyeXb9fCk85MoNRJjAd+Cst+gI9Cwpp1ysLMDY77k/a9eT3ExkgbGd6mdtfjAlP/o/rRMcqNwp9Pdhh6kkxrM0v1ceNSTbTeO7XCLvekqtRiwjWImhQs56JVbB/RLySNKtqjbpr7Zhn1m+p6+vmBmgwF3xBBvzziYfMm/vG1ZvvGIsI3dxRDWuSZ8+o63w7Y20M9NQn4QkqV6NFjX3conBiDGtDBKain2zj6Q== dino@blackbigone
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0JR6d9LWgvPCbvBajrbVly3cxX7ZkbH4+MUBu+ak2G5SGLbGBcwdi3JquBAT1+U/hl+TKKUUw1XjjjazdjgYCHWIguDWzmqoyT4bQN2aymNoqD35T+LWAaqwC36m95fRfJh3HSOtx7KXpsBZjvR40rg901f8ReIjBoL7G620rrsRDqaDS08Mm6TjThBrCeTYX2YzugodpUNP2evwFOBMrYw/TIcX5Lza8xRCctm8MRodsx/yvuYuZJSanVLs3Q6sJ/n9o20L8Jt1Fu1cnyxJTs9THiLOnZyrTBXvbKJymit6p3hfDpDlWtO/crNeyt0H8jJcZfiCnhQwfib2VMMqJw== erica@blackbigone
```

3: paste the ascii armored public keys you have in your text editor into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on each SSH server you want to login into. You must be the user you want to login. Create the file if it doesn't exists.
This way you are granting the permission to login to the server where you created the authorized_keys file to all users presenting with the given public keys.
The login is successful if the user have the correct matching private key.

Once logged in on the remote server, you can use sudo (you have to  configure /etc/sudoers file first with the visudo command) to execute commands by another user.
To avoid sudo to request for a password (because you are authenticated in /etc/sudoers...) you have to set the NOPASSWD flag, like the line below:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```